# OpenCV cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) returning -1

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I recently setup opencv 3.0 for python on my ubuntu pc using the following tutorial http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

So I ran the following code to get the number of frames of an mp4 video

```
   import cv2

   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4')
   length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
   print length
```

Strangely I get "-1" as output for "length". The video does infact load and I get accurate values for

```
   int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  #480
```

and

```
   int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))   #640
```

so its a wonder why frame count doesn't work. Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried using maybe `cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` or `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`. Altough in opencv 3.0.0 it should be without the `CV_` prefix.

Comment: the cv module/attribute doesn't exist. Apparently, it was removed in opencv 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the opencv build (as it also occured in c++). I ended up re-building my opencv and everything worked fine after