# c++ queue.front (); why not start from the first element?

Tags: c++, queue, buffer

I want to create a buffer. There are 4 streams. When each one fills 300 frames, I want to show it starting from the first element of all queues. But it all starts from the 301st frame. I cannot access the 300 Frame that I filled at the beginning.Another problem although i upload the queue with different data, .front() and back() operations on the queue returns the same data

```
Mat checkdata;
cv::subtract(frameQueue9001.back(), frameQueue9001.front(), checkdata, noArray(), -1);
printf("sthg  goes on: %f\n",cv::norm(checkdata, NORM_L2, noArray()));
```

**Resault: 0**

I will be grateful if you could help me.

Best regards.

I shared the code below for a single stream example

```
#include "highgui.hpp"
#include "videoio.hpp"
#include "imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <queue>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

#define quelen 300

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

queue<Mat> frameQueue9001;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    namedWindow("1", WINDOW_OPENGL);
    namedWindow("1");
    resizeWindow("1", 960, 510);
    moveWindow("1", 0, 0);


    string gst_pipe1 = "udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";

    VideoCapture cap1(gst_pipe1, CAP_GSTREAMER);

    Mat frame1;

    while (true) {

        cap1 >> frame1;
        frameQueue9001.push(frame1);   

        if(frameQueue9001.size() > quelen){ 

            imshow("1", frameQueue9001.front()); 

            frameQueue9001.pop();

        }
        //if (frame.empty())
        //    break;

        if (waitKey(1) == 'r')
            break;
    }
    destroyWindow("1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly.
With your condition:

```
if(frameQueue9001.size() > quelen)
```

You perform actions when your queue has 301 frames.
If you want the action with 300 frames, you need to correct that 
to an equals or greater equals condition.

With that correction, the 300th element can be accessed with

```
imshow("300", frameQueue9001.back());
```

Your query method of the first element seems correct to me.

Comment: it seems right to me too. but when running imshow ("1", frameQueue9001.front ()) code; frame starts from 301. I compare the back and the front. both take 301. frame. i want to see first frame.

Comment: Are you sure you get new frames in your capture? You perform cap1 >> frame1 but without checking that your capture is updated?

Comment: yes, i sure. I have a 30fps video. When I capture with this code. Starts from the 11th second. It starts from the 1st second when I don't use the queue. I don't understand where the 300 frames in the first 10 seconds fill up when I use queue.

Comment: Try checking the number of available frames: int totalFrameNumber = cap1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); How much do you get?

Comment: int totalFrameNumber = cap1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
it returns = "-1"

Comment: I have searched a little. The issue you are having is most likely related to OpenCV and not the queue library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604008/opencv-cap-getcv2-cap-prop-frame-count-returning-1    shows a similar problem. I cannot help you further with this, sorry, but it is not a queue issue.

Comment: thank you for your interest. I will examine the link.